# Remove backslash continuation character

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse some code with AST, but I'm having an issue because of backslash continuation character.

When I have a continuation character **\**, textwrap will not manage to dedent the code, I would like to know how to get rid of it.

```
code = """
    def foo():
        message = "This is a very long message that will probably need to wrap at the end of the line!\n \
And it actually did!"
"""

import textwrap
print textwrap.dedent(code)

import ast
ast.parse(textwrap.dedent(code))
```

I'm adding more details to clarify the question:

I have a module nemo.py with the following content:

```
class Foo(object):

    def bar(self):
        message = "This is a very long message that will probably need to wrap at the end of the line!\n \
And it actually did!"
```

and the main module trying to parse the code:

```
import ast
import nemo
import inspect
import textwrap

code = str().join(inspect.getsourcelines(nemo.Foo.bar)[0])
ast.parse(textwrap.dedent(code))
```

And the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kelsolaar/Documents/Development/Research/_BI.py", line 7, in <module>
    ast.parse(textwrap.dedent(code))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    def bar(self):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Why are you dedenting the code?

Comment: You probably want `\\n`, not `\n` there.

Comment: Because I have an indentation error from ast otherwise. I'm grabbing some code with inspect.getsourcelines, and if it's from a class method it's indented.

Comment: I just added some real code example to clarify what I'm doing.

Comment: is there a reason you cannot parse the whole source module and then traverse the resulting tree to get the desired subtree?

Comment: I think it's because it made sense to me to just retrieve what I needed ( Faster? ) but yeah it's actually a good idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you misunderstood what [`textwrap.dedent()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) does.

It *only* remove any ***common*** leading white spaces. In your case there's no common leading white space, therefore nothing is removed.

Moreover, what you want is actually `\\` instead of `\n \` in this case. This is because you actually want what is *printed* to be parsed. `\\` will print only one `\` and it's what you want. `\n \` will print a new line within `"..."` clause which is invalid.

Now consider this code:

```
>>> code = """
    def foo():
        message = "This is a very long message that will probably need to wrap at the end of the line! \\
    And it actually did!"
"""

>>> print textwrap.dedent(code)

def foo():
    message = "This is a very long message that will probably need to wrap at the e
nd of the line! \
And it actually did!"

>>> ast.parse(textwrap.dedent(code))
<_ast.Module object at 0x10e9e5bd0>
```

In this case there is ***common*** leading white spaces, and hence they are removed.

---

Edit:

If you want to get rid of the `\` all together, you can consider using `"""My sentence"""` for `message` in `def bar`.

Comment: I have updated my question because it was missing important details about what I'm trying to achieve and I do understand what textwrap.dedent does :)

Comment: @KelSolaar I updated my answer, the key point is that you can just use `"""` for message instead which will rid of the need for `\`.

Comment: Yeah I see, cheers! I'll mark your answer as valid since it addressed what I first described.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of the question I the following simple replace covers my needs: **code.replace("\\n", str())**

```
import ast
import nemo
import inspect
import textwrap

code = str().join(inspect.getsourcelines(nemo.Foo.bar)[0])
code.replace("\\\n", str())
ast.parse(textwrap.dedent(code))
```